# Modeling a spray painted polyurethane surface reflection

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, refraction, reflection

I'm modeling light interaction/reflection from a fiberglass surface with polyurethane epoxy (that is very  reflective) that has been spray painted with a matte black paint. I'm looking for some input - is it reasonable to approximate this as specular reflection from the polyurethane with a loss factor from the paint absorption? Is there a better way?

By way of context, this is a large water tank where we do experiments with underwater optical communication. I'm building a Monte Carlo-type simulation to match our experimental outputs. The wall surface reflections are giving me issues.

Comment: ""that has been spray painted with a matte black paint. I'm looking for some input - is it reasonable to approximate this as specular reflection from the polyurathane "" Are You shure that You know what "matte" and "specular" mean?

Comment: Georg, can you clarify? The painted surface is certainly not completely matte, as the paint was only one coat and has worn down over the years.

Comment: Why not just spray another coat?